# why class's this is readonly?

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to define a class. when I assign using

```
this = blah blah
```

the compiler reports "this is readonly"

when I change the class to struct, it looks fine, any idea?

Comment: Show the class please...

Comment: @Killercam, the class definition is irrelevant. The question is why is `this` inside a class not assignable.

Comment: How is it irrelevent. Clearly if the class is `protected`, or an `internal` child class, this could explain the compilers complaints.

Comment: "this" is a reference to the current instance of the class. It doesn't make sense to change the object to something else from that same object.

Comment: You're trying to make an apple become a banana. This doesn't make any sense to begin with, you can't make an instance of an object become something else.

Comment: @Killercam, it has nothing to do with protected or internal or an access modifier.  This question is as complete as it needs to be.

Comment: Dude. Okay, I appreciate due to Mark's answer below that this is not due to the classes protection level. However, an assumption was made in the deduction of this answer that he was doinig `this = BlahBlah` from within the containing class. This is _not_ explicitly stated in the question. This was my point.

Comment: @Killercam - `this = blahblah` can only be within the containing class since `this` is a keyword and is not a valid variable name.

Comment: Agreed. But as the answers point out - this is _not_ a valid use of `this`. So, in light of the OP having an issue it is resonable in this case to ask for clarification. Antway, it is irrelevent - have a good one...

Answer (score 22):

`this` in a `class` refers to the *reference*; **you cannot** reassign your own reference, but you can assign fields etc of the current instance.

`this` in a `struct` refers *to the value itself*; when you assign `this`, just like when you assign to any value-type variable / parameter, it is copying all of the *fields* over the top (as a memory-copy). That *is* possible, but is frankly rare to see in the wild. Or, as with classes, you can assign each of the fields separately.